# SAS Enterprise: Run multiple Process Flows at once

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I can't seem to find a straightforward way to run multiple process flows at once. I can select multiple and right click, but the 'Run' function disappears.

Any ideas? Programmatic or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want to run multiple flows *sequentially*, you would use an Ordered List to do that. You can include any number of programs in a process flow.

Process flows are intended to contain all of the items you want to run in one shot, so you would not normally run many entire process flows at once.  You can of course run one, then run the next one, if it's a few.  I don't believe you can link programs or objects from one process flow to another.

If you mean run *simultaneously*, then you can do that if you set your project up to allow parallel execution, and your server allows it.  File -> Project Properties -> Code Submission, check "Allow parallel execution on the same server" allows you to run multiple things at once - but be aware that each submission is in its own distinct SAS session and doesn't have direct access to the other submissions' temporary libraries or macro variables.

Comment: I have several imports and queries in each process flow (15 items per flow * 60 flows). Seems tedious/redundant to have to order the items in the flow when the flow itself is ordered. I can't seem to be able to add a whole process flow itself to the list. Am I missing something?

Comment: Largely, you're just identifying a weakness of EG.  If you don't manually order them (either using Ordered List, or by linking objects to each other), then they run in whatever order they were created in, I believe.  They specifically don't run in the order of the left-hand menu.  I try to name my programs/etc. in such a way that they sort properly (ie, PF1 might be running a sample, so the files are "SM1 0 Setup", "SM1 1a Load Control Data", "SM 1b Import Datafile", etc.) Then when you create the ordered list you can just select a bunch at once.

Comment: Technically speaking, the purpose of the PF is to link all of the objects you will run at one time together, so if you have 60x15 you really 'ought' to have them all in one PF (which would be crazy of course).  Then you could link (by hand) each object to the next one at a time, with 'condition on success' and 'condition on fail' and such.  Not necessarily practical for 15x60 objects of course...

Comment: Thanks. It's too late to name as I go :). Is it possible to create a program within a flow which runs the entire flow (or select queries/imports within the flow?)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I don't know if it's possible to use the 'conditions' to do what you want; no matter what though I imagine it would be somewhat tedious.

Comment: @Wael I would note that I'm not an expert here; we have a few EG users on SO but as a programmer's site we tend towards more DM types.  You might consider asking on the [SAS Community site](http://communities.sas.com/) and see if an EG expert might be able to help you, or even one of the SAS staff might chime in - Chris Hemedinger in particular often provides very helpful insights on EG.

Comment: Also - I don't know whether this could be useful, but there is the "Run Project" option.  That might or might not run things in the order you prefer, but it's possible that would work in your case.